# Get parentNode on change the CodeMirror

Tags: javascript, html, onchange, parent, codemirror

I have multiple div elements, each includes one codemirror element. I want to get id of div on changing codemirror inside.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".code").each(function (i, editorEl) {
        CodeMirror.fromTextArea(editorEl, {
            lineNumbers: true,
            mode: "xml"
        }).on("change", function(editorEl) {
            //console.log(editorEl.getValue());// this row works all right
            console.log("HOW I GET THE PARENT ELEMENT ID HERE");
        });
    });
});
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.65.5/codemirror.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.65.5/codemirror.min.js"></script>

<div id="poo"><textarea class="code" mode="text/html"></textarea></div>
<div id="foo"><textarea class="code" mode="text/html"></textarea></div>
<div id="boo"><textarea class="code" mode="text/html"></textarea></div>
<!-- ... -->
<div id="nnn"><textarea class="code" mode="text/html"></textarea></div>
```

Comment: If you don't shadow the `editorEl` variable, you can use `editorEl.parentNode.id`

Comment: Looks like you're using `jQuery`, so `$(editorEl).parent()` should give you the parent element. https://api.jquery.com/parent/ not tested

Comment: Thanks. Yes I use jquery because my real project is more complex. 
I've tried as you suggested but its not working too. 
I tried everything I knew, but editorEl does not turn into jquery object in any way.

Comment: Change `on("change", function(editorEl) { .. })`  to something like `on("change", function(codeMirror) { .. })` and it will

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I solved this problem:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".code").each(function (i, editorEl) {
        CodeMirror.fromTextArea(editorEl, {
            lineNumbers: true,
            mode: "xml"
        }).on("change", function(editorEl) {
            var parent_id = $(editorEl.getTextArea()).parent().attr("id")
            console.log(parent_id);
        });
    });
});
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.65.5/codemirror.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.65.5/codemirror.min.js"></script>

<div id="poo"><textarea class="code" mode="text/html"></textarea></div>
<div id="foo"><textarea class="code" mode="text/html"></textarea></div>
<div id="boo"><textarea class="code" mode="text/html"></textarea></div>
<!-- ... -->
<div id="nnn"><textarea class="code" mode="text/html"></textarea></div>
```